# SharePoint Online 2019 OOTB menus customization

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2019

I'm using SharePoint Online 2019 and I have to customize out of the box menu. I would like to know if it is fine to directly override SharePoint classes or I have to add a selector or custom class on top and then change the theme. What is the best practise to follow?

[image: codereview]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modern SharePoint, this is not a supported customisation. You should instead follow the advice Microsoft have given on [customising the modern experience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations).

If you are using classic SharePoint sites, then you can apply your own stylesheet using the Alternate CSS URL option that comes with the publishing feature. Though you should follow [Microsoft's advice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/portal-branding) on what should or shouldn't be customised.